# missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

I am getting this error   Error 4 The type or namespace name 'Sample' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\oadmin\sea\Controls\Dlg.cs 11 7 Controls

here i added Samplein **reference** section,,,then i used it as **Using Sample**,,i dont know why i am getting this error

this is the class

```
namespace sample
{

    public class Server
    {



        public class client
        {

        Bool sent = true

        }

}

}
```

Can i share exe,,this Sample is an exe

Comment: Paste your class please.

Comment: and post the line that causes the error!

Comment: Maybe sample is lowercase while you write it uppercase ?

Comment: Can i share exe,,this Sample is an exe

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because your namespace is sample and not Sample?
So if your Dlg namespace is different it needs to have a `using sample` line not `using Sample`.

Or perhaps your class is in another project within your solution and you need to include the hierarchy of namespaces?

Comment: Can i share exe,,this Sample is an exe

Comment: Your Server class is in an executable? Is it within a service? Would a class library server you better? How are you wanting to use the Server class? Could you give us some more information regarding what you are trying to do please?

Comment: Yes ,,here i need to access variable  "sent" in  different project,,i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace "sample" is lowercase, but you are referring to it in uppercase "Sample" ...

EDIT: You `Bool sent` is `internal`, it cannot be accessed from outside of the assembly

Comment: Can i share exe,,this Sample is an exe